# traversing a data strucuture

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I've tried a variety of different ways of selecting a date from rows in the for loop but I keep getting mistakes. It is a dictionary with 5 objects and I would like to iterate through the object named date. rows[i]['date'] doesn't work. What should I replace rows[i]['date']? SOLVED. When I iterate through times in my html code it is empty, why? NOT SOLVED

```
     for i in rows:
        date_split = str.split(rows[i]['date']) # I tried to use an integer to access date like row[0][5]
        just_time = date_split[1]
        if just_time == '00:00:00':
            just_time = 'All Day'
        else:
            just_time = just_time[0:5]
        times.append((just_time))

    rows.append((times))
    results.append((rows, printed_day, start_time, times))
```

Comment: Why are you using `rows` instead of `row` and where is `i` coming from?

Comment: `str.split` - str is a type, not a variable. You shouldn't use it as a variable name, and in this code it is not initialized

Comment: That was a typo in stackexhange sorry.

Comment: @Ni They are calling `split` from the `str` type. That should not be a problem

Comment: @Tanc27 Can you add more detail than *it doesn't work*

Comment: @MosesKoledoye It gives me the error  list indices must be integers, not dict

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I think they did it without meaning to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating on the rows, so at each iteration, `i` or `row` is a dictionary not some integer counter as you suppose.

```
for row in rows:
    # the loop variable row is a dictionary
    date_split = str.split(row['date']) # or row['date'].split()
    ...
```